# Highstock - custom tooltip data not being displayed for larger dataset

Tags: highcharts

I've got a highstock chart that displays properly for a dataset that is about 100 long.

I add a custom data to the point so that the tooltip displays this value.

```
  for j in i.data        
    point = 
      x:(moment(j[0], "YYYY-MM-DD").unix()) * 1000
      y:parseFloat(j[2])
      z:parseFloat(j[1])
```

And the tooltip is displayed via

```
  tooltip:
    pointFormat: '<span style="color:{series.color};">{series.name}</span>: <b>{point.z}</b><br/>',
    valueDecimals: 2
```

Above works fine and displays the "point.z" fine. But when I request a larger dataset, this value disappears. I compared the chart object and indeed the point.z value is gone.

I have read elsewhere that you have to set the "turboThreshold" so I set the values as

```
  plotOptions:
    series:
      turboThreshold:100000
    line:
      turboThreshold:100000
```

But the "point.z" is still not being displayed. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's caused by dataGrouping - in Highstock, when you are trying to display too many points, points are grouped. Only solution is to disable dataGrouping: `plotOptions.series.dataGrouping.enabled = false`